# How to easily distinguish salts physically? Edit

Tags: analytical-chemistry

I have basically 12 salts to identify in exams. They are ***

> Ammonium Carbonate, Ammonium Sulphate, Ammonium chloride, Aluminium
>   Nitrate , Aluminium Sulphate, Barium chloride, Calcium Carbonate,
>   Magnesium Carbonate, Magnesium Sulphate, Lead Nitrate, Zinc Sulphide,
>   Zinc Sulphate

***. I will be given one of them. I know all the tests I have to undertake to identify these salts (such as ash test, flame test, sodium carbonate extract tests etc). But I would like to know if there is any quick way to easily identify my salt on looking it or some easy tests so that I get a leverage over time and could finish my tests easier. I would like to know ASAP, as I have my exams tomorrow.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You just need to know the test for anion and cation

Comment: I know the tests, but it is practically time consuming.... If only i had an alternative way..

Comment: Then prioritize your step on the sequence for your test

Comment: @MukilanSC None of these tests are particularly time consuming. How fast are you meant to be doing this??

Comment: I have been given 3 hours for a volumetric analysis as well as this qualitative analysis and also this time includes summarizing the result of each individual test.

Comment: That is actually way more than what is required. I had to do a titration, a salt analysis and prepare a colloidal solution all in 2 hours. If you try to find the salt by blindly guessing, you will waste a lot of time. Start with dil. H2SO4 test, then do flame test, then do ash test. By now, you would've identified the radicals.

Answer (score 4):

Draw a matrix of cations vs anions, mark the possible combinations, and calculate the probabilities.

The chances are **4/12** for a sulphate, 3/12 for a carbonate, etc.

I wouldn't start testing for sulphides ;-)